# Curvature in the hyperboloid model

Tags: geometry, terminology, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm currently making a [R package](https://github.com/stla/gyro) which implements Ungar's approach to hyperbolic geometry, for the hyperboloid model. In this theory, there is a parameter $s>0$ which controls the curvature of the hyperbolic segments:

[image]

I'm wondering whether this parameter has a devoted name? Would you know? I know Ungar's theory but I'm ignorant in classical hyperbolic geometry in the hyperboloid model, maybe this parameter also appears in the classical theory?

Comment: what is Ungar's approach?

Comment: @Thomas The *gyrovector spaces*. An intro can be found [on my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/hyperbolicPolyhedra.html);

Comment: I suspect, the parameter $s$ here is some function of the curvature of the hyperbolic space. I looked at Ungar's formalism at some point in the past, but decided that it's not worth my time trying to learn it. I do not see any advantage comparing to, say, the hyperboloid model. If you can reformulate your question using the standard hyperboloid model, you might get an answer here.